# JPA ManyToOne OneToMany constraint violation

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, openjpa

I have two entities Fichier and Categorie :

```
Fichier.java

@Entity
@Table(name="\"Fichier\"")
public class Fichier implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="\"idFichier\"", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int idFichier;

    ...

    @JoinColumn(name = "\"idCategorie\"", referencedColumnName = "\"idCategorie\"")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = ALL )
    private Categorie categorieParent;

...
```

And Categorie.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Categorie\"")
public class Categorie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="\"idCategorie\"", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int idCategorie;

    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categorieParent", cascade = ALL)
    private List<Categorie> listeCategorie = new ArrayList<Categorie>();
    @JoinColumn(name = "\"idCatParent\"", referencedColumnName = "\"idCategorie\"")
    @ManyToOne()
    private Categorie categorieParent;
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Fichier
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="categorieParent", cascade = ALL)
    private List<Fichier> listeFichier;

    ...

    public Categorie addListeCategorie(Categorie listeCategorie){
        getListeCategorie().add(listeCategorie);
        listeCategorie.setCategorieParent(this);
        return listeCategorie;
}

    ....
```

Main.java

```
Categorie c =new Categorie();
Fichier f= new Fichier();
c.addFichier(f);
em.persist(c);
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: THE INSERT OR UPDATE VALUE OF FOREIGN KEY "Schema.Fichier.Contient" , the insert value of a foreign key must be equal to the value of the parent key SQLCODE=-530, SQLSTATE=23503, DRIVER=3.63.123 {prepstmnt -640961458 INSERT INTO "Schema"."Fichier" ("contenu", "description", "niveau", "nom", "type", "idCategorie") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} [code=-530, state=23503]
```

The error indicates a violation of integrity constrains, but why?
I already try to persist child before parent, but still the same error.

Comment: How are your Ids generated? There is no @GeneratedValue annotation and you don't set them in your code.

Comment: I added in Fichier and Categorie `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

But i get this error `Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: "IDCATEGORIE"  is not permitted in this context.. `

The database is already configured to generate id.

Comment: You could set the strategy to `AUTO` - the provider should then select an applicable strategy. Can you verify that your entities do not have an Id before the persist?

Comment: Without adding Fichier to Categorie, I can persist Categorie.
AUTO doesen't work cause it don't find the default provider strategy.
IDENTITY don't work even if I don't add Fichier to Categorie. Full error is `Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: "IDCATEGORIE" n'est pas autorisé dans le contexte dans lequel il est utilisé.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.63.123 {prepstmnt 301873790 INSERT INTO "Schema"."Categorie" ("description", "nom", "idCatParent") VALUES (?, ?, ?)} [code=-206, state=42703]`

Comment: This is strange. I have no experience with OpenJPA, but this could be a bug. What happens if you remove the `insertable=false` restriction and define your own Id values before commit?

Comment: If i remove it, it try to insert "IDCATEGORIE" and it can't work cause database didn't accept value in this field.

And if i configure database to accept value, i have the same error : `Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: "IDCATEGORIE" n'est pas autorisé dans le contexte dans lequel il est utilisé.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.63.123 {prepstmnt 301873790 INSERT INTO "Schema"."Categorie" ("description", "nom", "idCatParent") VALUES (?, ?, ?)} [code=-206, state=42703]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either set value of `@Id` column explicitly or map it with some auto-generation strategy.

Comment: I added in Fichier and Categorie `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

But i get this error `Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: "IDCATEGORIE"  is not permitted in this context.. `

The database is already configured to generate id.

Comment: Try removing `insertable=false, updatable=false`